# Getting following error while creating new project in visual studio 2015 using template 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, template10

[Getting following error while creating new project in visual studio 2015 using template 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRg9Y.jpg)

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Universal.TemplateWizards, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

How to remove this error? I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the template.

Comment: Did you install the windows 10 sdk?  Sounds like you are missing the the universal windows app project type

Comment: With Update2 came SDK 1.3.1 yea got me too... Try running the change wizard for VS.NET bet there will be a suggested update that wasn't pushed into the client itself as a notification... ;(

Comment: I have installed SDK 1.3.1 with update 2 and it helps in creating project but now there is another error while i tried to build the project .

error code- CS0012

error description- The type 'ActionCollection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: project.json, change "Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.UWP.Managed" : "1.1.*" also make sure that Microsoft.NETCore.UnversialWindowsPlatform: "5.1.0" is in the file as well...if it is 5.0, change it.

Answer (score 0):

I went in to uninstall the newest version of the XAML Interactivity assembly and went back to the previous. I think is was 1.0.0.3 or something, rebuild. It worked.

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped in a great way and this method worked @Bjarne